# Problemas de compatibilidad con tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

Me encuentro haciendo uso de un modelo preentrenado por lo cual estoy trabajando con tensorflow hub para traerlo. el codigo es el siguiente

```
import cv2
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width = 1028
height = 1028

#Load image by Opencv2
img = cv2.imread('splash.jpg')
#Resize to respect the input_shape
inp = cv2.resize(img, (width , height ))

#Convert img to RGB
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(inp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# COnverting to uint8
rgb_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(rgb, dtype=tf.uint8)

#Add dims to rgb_tensor
rgb_tensor = tf.expand_dims(rgb_tensor , 0)

import tensorflow_hub as hub


# Loading model directly from TensorFlow Hub
detector = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/lite2/detection/1")
#detector =hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/classification/4")

# Loading csv with labels of classes
labels = pd.read_csv('labels.csv', sep=';', index_col='ID')
labels = labels['OBJECT (2017 REL.)']

# Creating prediction
boxes, scores, classes, num_detections = detector(rgb_tensor)

# Processing outputs
pred_labels = classes.numpy().astype('int')[0] 
pred_labels = [labels[i] for i in pred_labels]
pred_boxes = boxes.numpy()[0].astype('int')
pred_scores = scores.numpy()[0]

# Putting the boxes and labels on the image
for score, (ymin,xmin,ymax,xmax), label in zip(pred_scores, pred_boxes, pred_labels):
    if score < 0.5:
        continue

    score_txt = f'{100 * round(score)}%'
    img_boxes = cv2.rectangle(rgb,(xmin, ymax),(xmax, ymin),(0,255,0),2)      
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(img_boxes, label,(xmin, ymax-10), font, 1.5, (255,0,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(img_boxes,score_txt,(xmax, ymax-10), font, 1.5, (255,0,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

obteniendo como salida esto

```
2024-01-13 21:42:55.305005: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.

2024-01-13 21:43:01.630640: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\util.py:74: The name tf.train.SessionRunHook is deprecated. Please use tf.estimator.SessionRunHook instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\native_module.py:92: The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\saved_model_module.py:40: The name tf.saved_model.constants.LEGACY_INIT_OP_KEY is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.saved_model.constants.LEGACY_INIT_OP_KEY instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\resolver.py:120: The name tf.gfile.MakeDirs is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.makedirs instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\resolver.py:120: The name tf.gfile.MakeDirs is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.makedirs instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\module_v2.py:120: The name tf.saved_model.load_v2 is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\module_v2.py:120: The name tf.saved_model.load_v2 is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load instead.
```

lo extraño es que en colab funciona, incluso intente igualar la version de vscode con la que tengo en colab(2.15.0) y nada aun. porfa les agradeceria su ayuda